# Using select2 how can I collapse/expand optgroups?

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm using [select2](https://select2.github.io/) (v 4.0.3) with Bootstrap 3 and I have to display several hundreds of alternatives per optgroup. Now I wish to collapse/expand the optgroups on click to make it a bit more manageable. I couldn't find any info on this so I thought I'd post a question.

I found an approach to this problem but I couldn't get it to work (it seems a bit outdated [issue #730](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/730)). The basic problem with that approach now is that in the current version of select2 elements aren't created until they are needed. Also, the class names seem to have changed a bit, as have apparently the names of events in the move to the latest version.

So far I've managed to get the collapse/expand functionality to work for the optgroups, but issues arise when the user provides text input (check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keski/gdavhkhj/)).

```
$(function () {
  var data = [
    {
      text: "Group 1",
      children: [
        { id: 'A1', text: 'a1'},
        { id: 'B2', text: 'b2'},
        { id: 'C3', text: 'c3'}]
    },
    {
      text: "Group 2",
      children: [
        { id: 'A2', text: 'a2'},
        { id: 'B3', text: 'b3'},
        { id: 'C1', text: 'c1'}
      ]
    }];

  $('#mySelect')
    .select2({data: data, placeholder : 'Select one' });

  // Toggle group on click
  $('.select2')
  .on('click', function(){
    $('.select2-results__option').on('click', function(){
      $(this).find('.select2-results__options--nested').toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

When the text input is used select2 runs the search and the events I've registered are dropped. My plan was to capture text input and check if the input field is empty or not, based on which I can decide to recreate the optgroup listeners or show all optgroups. Any help in this direction would be appreciated.